# How to give kind name in DatastoreIO.v1.write

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to read from a kind in google datastore and apply some transformations  and write back to another kind.  I am using google dataflow to achieve this.  While reading from Datastore, we are able to give Kind.  But not able to give Kind while writing.  How to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Oops, I just noticed you were asking for Java. `DatastoreIO.v1.write` looks at the java equivalent of `WriteToDatastore` for me, in which case you have to set up your entity (including kind) in the previous step. Check out `CreateEntityFn` in this example. https://github.com/mbrukman/apache-beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/cookbook/DatastoreWordCount.java#L197

ORIGINAL:

This is how I do it

```
import apache_beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import WriteToDatastore
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import entity_pb2
from googledatastore import helper

class MakeEntity(object):
    def __init__(self, project):
        self._project = project

    def make(self, element):
        try:
            entity = entity_pb2.Entity()
            helper.add_key_path(entity.key, 'EntityKind', element['id'])
            helper.add_properties(entity, {
                "created": datetime.datetime.now(),
                "email": unicode(element['email'],
                "count": int(element['count'],
                "amount": float(element['amount'],
            })
            return entity
        except:
            logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
            raise

def build_pipeline(project, pipeline_options):
    p = apache_beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    _ = \
        (p
         # other transforms
         | 'create entity' >> apache_beam.Map(MakeEntity(project=project).make)
         | 'write to datastore' >> WriteToDatastore(project=project))
    return p
```

**Edit #2:** I adjusted your code to more closely follow the example I linked to. Hopefully this works

```
public class ModifyEntityKindFn extends DoFn<Entity, Entity> { 

    @ProcessElement 
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) { 

        Key.Builder keyBuilder = makeKey(NEW_KIND, inputEntity.getKey());
        keyBuilder.getPartitionIdBuilder().setNamespaceId(NEW_NAMESPACE); 
        Entity.Builder entityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder().setKey(keyBuilder.build()); 
        entityBuilder.getMutableProperties().put("content", makeValue(context.element()).build());
        context.output(entityBuilder.build()); 

    } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I am using following code to copy data in datastore from one kind to another kind

Comment: public class ModifyEntityKindFn extends DoFn<Entity, Entity> {
     @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
      Entity inputEntity = context.element();
      Key.Builder keyBuilder = makeKey(NEW_KIND, inputEntity.getKey());
      keyBuilder.getPartitionIdBuilder().setNamespaceId(NEW_NAMESPACE);
      Entity.Builder entityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder().setKey(keyBuilder.build());
      entityBuilder.putAllProperties(inputEntity.getPropertiesMap());      
      context.output(entityBuilder.build());
    }  }

Comment: Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    PCollection<Entity> entities = p.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().read()
        .withProjectId(options.getDataset())
        .withQuery(query)
        .withNamespace(options.getNamespace()));


    entities.apply(ParDo.of(new GetContentFn()));
 
 entities.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(options.getDataset()));
 p.run();   compilation is failing with unrecognized method inputEntity.getPropertiesMap()  ,

Comment: Unfortunately I operate in python so I'm a little out of my element here, but check "Edit #2" in my answer.